# Is it possible for 2 windows managed by Windows to have the same window handle value?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, process, window

Is it possible for 2 windows managed by Windows to have the same window handle value?

Consider both cases when these 2 windows are opened by the same process and when these 2 windows are opened by 2 different processes.

Comment: funny, msdn does not specify if its unique, but for aim of functionality i think they are

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quick answer: no, it's not possible if they are inside the same desktop, every window handle issued by the window manager is unique (inside its desktop) throughout all the existence of the window, otherwise it couldn't uniquely identify such window on the <s>system</s> current <s>window station</s> desktop (which is defined by MSDN as "a logical display surface" that "contains user interface objects such as windows, menus, and hooks; it can be used to create and manage windows").

---

Long answer:

The issue is discussed [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/c326445b-c9a3-4295-94cd-f311e7e914ab), which points to [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ntdebugging/archive/2007/01/04/desktop-heap-overview.aspx). It seems that `HWND`s are local to desktops , so you *can* have two identical `HWND`s that point to two different windows, but they are necessarily *in two separated desktops*, so there's no ambiguity (the WM handle you pass to every user32 function refers implicitly to the current desktop, to go to another one you have to use `SetThreadDesktop`, and this call fails if your thread owns any desktop-contained object into the current desktop).

On the other hand, when a window is destroyed, its handle *can* be reused, but IIRC the window manager employs some techniques to avoid immediately reusing a handle.

Comment: As far as I know handles are unique across virtual desktops (eg. the UAC window on the secure desktop will never have the handle of explorer on your 'real' desktop)

Comment: @0x5f3759df: from what I read into the MSDN it seems that you're correct, I'll fix my answer.

Comment: regarding the desktops managed by Windows, it seems EnumDesktopWindows will give identical HWNDs, and EnumWindows will give inidentical HWNDs?

Comment: I don't understand your question... :S

Answer (score 4):

Every window open at a particular time will have a unique handle.
However, they can be reused once a window is closed.